# Searching a Pandas Dataframe that contains special characters?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, special-characters

I'm working on some exploratory data analysis and performing relatively simple tasks like counting how many times a certain string appears in a Pandas column.

My problem is that this column contains multiple characters that Pandas doesn't like (primarily: '@', '#', '()'). These characters are important and I don't want to edit my original data to replace them with placeholders.

How can I use functions like pandas.Series.str.count with characters like: @, #, (), etc?

I don't get any error message, it just says there are zero instances of my string in any row - which I can plainly see is false.

I have figured out that I can convert the pandas column/series in question to a list (df.tolist()), and then I can use list.count() and it behaves perfectly, but doesn't offer me as much functionality as keeping it as the original pandas series (like keeping the row index, for instance).

I've googled this for hours and figured this must be a really common problem, but I haven't found a solution I've understood.

Comment: pandas should recognise these characters. can you give an example of the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: What are you suing the count for? I ask because if it is just for information, you can do it without disturbing the original df. Also, a snippet of input and expected output goes a long-way in getting you better results. You should consider that approach.